# VBA Excel Merging dynamic ranges from two sheets into one, 1004 paste error

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, merge, range

I'm trying to merge data from two different spread sheets into one which becomes the data source for a couple pivot tables. Both sheets have different layouts so I'm looping through the first sheet to find the column, copy the data range below it and then paste into the wDATA sheet. Then go to the next sheet, find the same headers and then paste below the first block.
I'm getting my favorite error, 1004. I've tried different proprieties and methods but it won't paste so here's what I started with. [Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?6o0zxpaxzou9n85) is a file with the larger bit and data. I promise its clean. Any Help?

```
            For x = 1 To iEndcol 'TOP SECTION OF DATA  -FBL5N
            If InStr(Cells(1, x), "Sold") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lEndRowA, 1))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "Invoice#" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lEndRowA, 2))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "Billing Doc" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lEndRowA, 3))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Cust Deduction") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lEndRowA, 4))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "A/R Adjustment" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(lEndRowA, 5))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Possible Repay") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(lEndRowA, 6))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Profit") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowA, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lEndRowA, 7))
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ' DO NOT REDEFINE lEndrowA until all data is moved
    ' Fills in data from the second source, wLID
    If Not wLID Is Nothing Then
        wLID.Activate
        lEndRowB = Cells(4650, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        iEndcol = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        For x = 1 To iEndcol 'BOTTOM
            If InStr(Cells(1, x), "Sold-To") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 1))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "Invoice#" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 2))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "Billing Doc" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 3))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Cust Deduction") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 4))
            ElseIf Cells(1, x) = "A/R Adjustment" Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 5))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Possible Repay") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 6))
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(1, x), "Profit") Then
                Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(lEndRowB, x)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 7))
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
wDATA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 1))
```

You've qualified the `Range` object, but not the `Cells` objects. Without qualification, the `ActiveSheet` is assumed. Try this instead:

```
wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(1, 1), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB, 1))
```

Comment: OOoooo, I like this better. I came back to kill the question because I figured out I could use Activesheet property. But this is much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

The are a number of problems with this code

1. You are not qualifying all your references to `Range`'s and `Cells`.  This results in reference tot the active sheet, not always what you want.
2. You are copying formulas from your source sheets, which results in incorrect calculations.  probably want to copy values instead
3. Not all your variables are defined or set
4. Your indexing into `wData` when copying from `FBL5N` overwrites the headers
5. Your indexing into `wData` when copying from `Line Item Detail` seems wrong (overrights first data set

Here's your code refactored to correct these errors (note some code is commented out where it makes no sence)

```
Option Explicit

Sub AR_Request_Populate()
'
'
'       WORKING
'       TODO: Pull in sales info and pricing folder, Finsih off Repay
'
'
'AR_Request_Populate Macro
' Refreshes Pivot Tables and fills out the AR Request sheet. Ends with copy,paste, special: values.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: None
'

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wFBL5N As Worksheet
    Dim wLID As Worksheet
    Dim wDATA As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim iEndcol As Integer
    Dim lEndRowA As Long, lEndRowB As Long

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim y As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim v

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wLID = wb.Sheets("Line Item Detail")
    Set wFBL5N = wb.Sheets("FBL5N")
    If wFBL5N Is Nothing And wLID Is Nothing Then GoTo 102
    'On Error GoTo 101
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wb.Sheets("wDATA").Visible = True
    Set wDATA = wb.Sheets("wDATA")

    ' Let's make a data sheet....
    ' DO NOT REDEFINE lEndrowA until all data is moved
    If Not wFBL5N Is Nothing Then
        With wFBL5N
            lEndRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            iEndcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            wFBL5N.Copy _
                after:=wb.Sheets("FBL5N")
            'Merges Ref. Key 1 into Profit Center
            For x = 1 To iEndcol
                If InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Profit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Next
            For j = 1 To iEndcol
                If InStr(.Cells(1, j), "Ref") > 0 And InStr(Cells(1, j), "1") > 0 Then Exit For
            Next
            For y = 1 To lEndRowA
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(y, x)) Then
                    .Cells(y, j).Copy Destination:=.Cells(y, x)
                End If
            Next
            'And we move it...
            For x = 1 To iEndcol 'TOP SECTION OF DATA  -FBL5N
                If InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Sold") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 1), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 1)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "Invoice#" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 2), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 2)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "Billing Doc" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 3), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 3)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Cust Deduction") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 4), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 4)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "A/R Adjustment" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 5), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 5)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Possible Repay") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 6), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 6)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Profit") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowA, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(2, 7), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA, 7)) = v
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If


    ' DO NOT REDEFINE lEndrowA until all data is moved
    ' Fills in data from the second source, wLID
    If Not wLID Is Nothing Then
        'wLID.Activate
        With wLID
            lEndRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            iEndcol = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
            For x = 1 To iEndcol 'BOTTOM
                If InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Sold-To") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 1), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 1)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "Invoice#" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 2), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 2)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "Billing Doc" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 3), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 3)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Cust Deduction") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 4), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 4)) = v
                ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "A/R Adjustment" Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 5), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 5)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Possible Repay") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 6), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 6)) = v
                ElseIf InStr(.Cells(1, x), "Profit") Then
                    v = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lEndRowB, x))
                    wDATA.Range(wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + 1, 7), wDATA.Cells(lEndRowA + lEndRowB - 1, 7)) = v
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If

99
    'wARadj.Select
   ' Range("A1:K1").Select
    MsgBox "All Done", vbOKOnly, "Yup."

100
    'wBDwrk.Visible = False
    'wPCwrk.Visible = False
    'wDATA.Visible = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End

101     '101 and greater are error handlings for specific errors
    MsgBox "Sorry, there was an error and you might not be able to use this macro. If there are formula errors, delete the formulas and try the macro again. If this wasn't the problem, send a copy of this file and a breif message about what you were doing to me at:" _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "__________" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " I will try and let you know what happened ASAP.", , "I've gone Wonky."
GoTo 100

102
    MsgBox "This Macro can only run on a formatted Deduction Report or an FBL5N." _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you are using either one, please exactly name the tabs 'Line Item Detail' for a Dedution Report or 'FBL5N' for an FBL5N" _
            , vbOKOnly, "Line Item Detail or FBL5N Missing"
GoTo 100

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the first time someone has helped me by editing my code and a lot of things I have been reading make sense now. Thanks, this is really cool.

Comment: This is the first time someone has helped me by editing my code and a lot of things I have been reading make sense now. Thanks, this is really cool. <br/><br/>Oh yes sir there is a lot more wrong with the original code. But what you showed me will help make it cleaner and workable.

Comment: Wow my brain could be going, I can't hit the keys right anymore. Stack overflow needs to have more than one accepted answer. What is this? Fighting for upboats?